# How to add dropdown in post in WordPress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have written 5 posts(See Image-1) on the Indian Army currently on my website.

**Problem**- I want to create a dropdown of these 5 posts and insert them in empty space(See Image-2) in each of these posts, also when I write a new article on the army, this dropdown gets updated automatically. It should be like what is shown in Image-3 Below.

Please help me fix this issue.

Image-1

[image]

Image- 2
[image]

Image 3
[image]

Comment: Do you just want a dropdown list of all the 'chapters' at the top of all of your posts?

Comment: Yes at the top and at bottom

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `shortcode` in the `functions.php` of your theme and then insert it into the post. Sample code:

```
<?php
function shortcode_indian_army_post_dropdown() {
    $args = array(
        'category_name'  => 'indian-army',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );

    $posts = get_posts( $args );
    
    $html = '';
    ob_start();

    if ( ! empty( $posts ) ) {
        ?>
        <select name="indian-army-posts" id="indian-army-posts">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <?php foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
                setup_postdata( $post );
                echo '<option value="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</option>';
            }
            wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </select>
        <?php
        $html = ob_get_contents();
    }
    
    ob_get_clean();
    
    return $html;
}

add_shortcode( 'indian_army_post_dropdown', 'shortcode_indian_army_post_dropdown' );
```

Now add `[indian_army_post_dropdown]` inside the post content.